# java.lang.NumberFormatException

Tags: java

Подскажите как перевести `String` в массив `int`, чтобы не выдавало ошибку:

```
NumberFormatException: For input string: "70 (70 - это последний элемент в String)
```

---

```
String strArr[] = s.split(" ");
int numArr[] = new int[strArr.length];
for (int i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++)
{
    numArr[i] = Integer.parseInt(strArr[i]);
}
```

Comment: Покажите исходную строку.

Comment: Строка считывается с файла, там она содержится в виде  (1 2 4 20 30 40 53 70)

Comment: Перед `String strArr[] = s.split(" ");` выведите `s` на консоль и покажите вывод.

Comment: Так и выводит:1 2 4 20 30 40 53 70

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно, в самом конце строки у вас есть перенос строки. У строк в Java есть метод, который удаляет *ведущие* пробелы в строке: [trim()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim())

Рекомендую вам переписать ваш код вот так:

```
String strArr[] = s.split(" ");
int numArr[] = new int[strArr.length];
for (int i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++)
{
    numArr[i] = Integer.parseInt(strArr[i].trim());
}
```

Comment: Спс, бро....выручил